# Spring пример асинхронного метода с прогрессом исполнения

Tags: java, spring, асинхронность

Хочется понять, как должен выглядеть асинхронный метод, который "делает работу" и пока он ее делает - его можно опрашивать на оставшееся время и получать ответ в json, типа:

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "time": 155,
     "work": object
 }
```

Очень условный метод для примера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/work/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Work getWork(@PathVariable("id") int wId) {

    // do something
    return work;
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть множество способов сделать это. Например:

```
public class WorkerEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private String taskName;
    private Integer percentComplete;

    public WorkerEvent(Object source, String taskName, Integer percentComplete) {
        super(source);
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.percentComplete = percentComplete;
    }

    // Аксессоры
}

@Service
public SomeDispatcherServer {
    private final Map<String, Integer> tasks = new HashMap<>();

    public void setTaskProgress(String taskName, Integer percentComplete) {
        tasks.put(taskName, percentComplete);
    }

    public Integer getTaskProgress(String taskName) {
        tasks.getOrDefault(taskName, 0);
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeWorkerService {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Async
    public void someAsyncMethod() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // Какие-то длительные операции
            publisher.publishEvent(new WorkerEvent("SomeTask", i));
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class WorkerEventListener implements ApplicationListener<WorkerEvent> {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDispatcherServer dispatcherService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(WorkerEvent event) {
        dispatcherService.setTaskProgress(event.getTaskName(),
                                          event.getPercentComplete());
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class SomeController {
    private static class WorkInfo {
        private final Integer percentComplete;

        public WorkInfo(Integer percentComplete) {
            this.percentComplete = percentComplete;
        }

        public Integer getPercentComplete() {
            return percentComplete;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private SomeDispatcherServer dispatcherService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{taskName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public WorkInfo getWork(@PathVariable String taskName) {
        return new WorkInfo(dispatcherService.getTaskProgress(taskName));
    }
}
```